# Click a hyperlink using powershell

Tags: powershell, hyperlink

I need to click on a hyperlink in a aspx webform using powershell. How can I achieve this?
Also that link shows a drop down menu and I have to select the right option from that link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate('http://www.somewhere.com')
while($ie.busy) {sleep 1}
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | where-object {$_.innerText -eq 'Click here'}
$link.click()
```

Comment: Thanks your help i had to use following lines to access frame's content.                                                           $dmeContExpFrame = $ie.Document.getElementById("ContentFrame")
$dmecontexpframedoc = $dmeContExpFrame.contentWindow
$dmeContExpFramedoc2 = $dmecontexpframedoc.Document

$links = $dmeContExpFramedoc2.getElementsByTagName('A')
$links | select innerText

Comment: what does the 'A' in getElementsbyTagName indicate?

Comment: I'd guess the `A` is from the HTML `<A href=` tag.

Comment: if the innerText is variable you can use Regex as following: `{$_.innerText -Match '^a.*'}`

Answer (score 0):

**Its works**

```
while($ie.busy) {sleep 5} 
$dmeContExpFrame = $ie.Document.getElementById("portfolio_frameset") 
$dmecontexpframedoc = $dmeContExpFrame.contentWindow 
$dmeContExpFramedoc2 = $dmecontexpframedoc.Document 
$click = $dmeContExpFramedoc2.getElementsByTagName("b") | ?{$_.innerText -Match "Monitor Library"}
$click.click()
```