# Using PowerShell to set ASP page DropDown Box that has VBScript

Tags: asp.net, powershell, vbscript

I am hoping I'm phrasing this question correctly.

We have an internal ticketing system that uses an ASP page for creating a new ticket.  Using PowerShell, I can set the values of certain DropDown boxes correctly.  However I'm having a problem where an embedded VBScript is supposed to run if that DropDown box is manually clicked/changed based on the `.Value` which isn't being read since PowerShell programmatically set the value.

Can PowerShell do this?  Yes, I know there is a community extension for web-testing, I'd rather rely on built-in commands in PowerShell to simplify things as much as possible for distributing my script.

The ASP page source contains `<Script Language="VBScript"> 'Client Side sub procedures`

I'm guessing the Sub routine will run if the DropDown box contains a `.Value` as selected by the user.  Could I get PowerShell to run this VBScript Sub routine?  Or run the `onchange=` element?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this would help or push you in the right direction?

[Click a hyperlink using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644940/powershell-click-on-a-hyperlink)

Comment: I'm not very sure PowerShell can interact with the embedded javascript element `onchange` that's part of a TextBox.  At least I have not found any examples documenting such.  Thinking out loud, I might only have to set focus there then set focus some place else.